# Undefined index error after logout

Tags: php, html, cakephp

I am getting undefined index error after logging out from my web page. When i stay loged in it is all good, but when there is no1 loged in it shows error. Session active i checked.  Undefined index: User from

```
if($_SESSION['Auth']['User']['role'] == 'admin') {
    echo 'some html code';
}
```

only when no user is loged in! Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have destroy the session when logout. so `$_SESSION['Auth']['User']['role']` on login page.

Comment: Why are you referring to `$_SESSION` in a CakePHP application?

Answer (score 2):

If no one is logged in, then `$_SESSION['Auth']['User']['role']` does not exist, so you are getting the undefined index error. Try this instead:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['Auth']['User']['role']) 
    && $_SESSION['Auth']['User']['role'] == 'admin') { 
    // admin is logged in
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, finnished my project atlast.

Answer (score 0):

you have destroy the session when logout. so `$_SESSION['Auth']['User']['role']` on login page.

But you can avoid the error which you are getting by checking `isset`

```
if(isset($_SESSION['Auth']['User']['role']) && $_SESSION['Auth']['User']['role'] == 'admin') {
    echo 'some html code';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
if(isset($_SESSION['Auth']['User']['role']))
{ 
        $_SESSION['Auth']['User']['role'] == 'admin') 
        {
            echo 'some html code';
        }
}
```